# C "Generic"Struct build

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I want to construct a struct which has an array of unknown number of rows and 2 columns
something like

```
struct s
{
     cinst char*** s;
}
const char* str1[][2] = {"1","2",
                        "3","4",
                        "5","6"};
s s1 = {str1};
const char* str2[][2] = {"1","2",
                        "3","4"};

s s2 = {str2};
```

The code fails in compilation.How can I solve the problem?

Comment: The RHS of your initialization lists are one dimensional when your arrays are 2D arrays of strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from the typo `cinst` and the missing semicolon and assuming (without letting us know) `s` and `struct s` are the same type

your problem is that the types of `str1` and the struct member `s` are not compatible

- `str1` is of type `const char*[][2]`
- the struct member is of type `const char***`

Forcing the compiler to assume `str1` is of type `const char ***` solves your immediate problem, ie, the program compiles and "works", but you really need to understand that **arrays are not pointers** and **pointers are not arrays**. See section 6 of the [c-faq site](http://c-faq.com/).

```
struct s
{
     const char*** s;
};
const char* str1[][2] = {"1","2",
                        "3","4",
                        "5","6"};
struct s s1 = {(const char ***)str1};
const char* str2[][2] = {"1","2",
                        "3","4"};

struct s s2 = {(const char ***)str2};
```

Comment: This is C. struct type names are not automatically typedefed!

Comment: Thanks @celavek: you're right. Post ninja-edited to reflect that.

Comment: Whynot just a typedef? Also why three indirections when the initializer is still in 1 dimension (of 2 elem chars)?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is not C. (and there is a semicolon missing)

struct s { ...}; does not introduce a type "s", it is *not* a typedef.
eg you cannot use:
struct s { ...};
s my_thing;
(even if you add the missing semicolon)
Maybe you are confusing C and C++ ?

Answer (score -2):

```
struct s
{
    cinst char** s;
};
const char str1[][2] = {"1","2",
                "3","4",
                "5","6"};
s s1 = {str1};
const char str2[][2] = {"1","2",
                "3","4"};

s s2 = {str2};
```

Removing the third indirection / dereference will fix this.

Comment: -1 for providing code that does not compile; worse it does not respect basic syntax of the language in question. What language is that you've presented your program in?

Comment: It takes me several minutes to pass it through my compiler as the posted code requires separation of body from header. It addresses the syntactic shortcomings of the OP.

Comment: I'm sorry, your answer does not address any of the OP's problems. It's just plain wrong. And the excuse is pretty lame to be honest.